# Zeroconf / Bonjour and Delphi

Tags: delphi, zeroconf

Has anyone toyed with, or got an example for loading and using the dnsds.dll (zeroconf / bonjour / dns-ds) via Delphi. I have a c# version, but that isn't quite what I want.

Thanks

Comment: That's odd, I can't seem to find dnsds.dll on my system, how can I get it installed?

Comment: It may well come with iTunes.

Comment: It's called dnssd.dll and gets installed with iTunes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an encapsulation of Bonjour up and running with a code-first framework, though it does also provide some basic components.  You can obtain the framework as part of my delphi.libs repo on github:

https://github.com/deltics/delphi.libs/tree/master/bonjour

Comment: I know it is a very old answer but:
Why this is an accepted answer?

Comment: @N-iceman - LOL and very good question.  What I should have done is come back here and updated the answer with a link to the referenced library once it was published.  Which I have done now.  Thanks for the bump!  :)

Answer (score 2):

RemObjects SDK has ZeroConf support in the latest version:
http://www.remobjectssdk.com/

Very nice software, it's worth the price!

Comment: If you have a use for RemoObjects then getting ZeroConf support "in the box" is fabulous.  But it's not worth the price (US$400) simply to get ZeroConf support.